# What's wrong with this integral?

Tags: integration

I try to solve this integral $\int_0^a2 x^2 e^{-x^2} dx$ and use substitution $u=x^2$, I think the integral equals to $\int_0^{a^2} u e^{-u}du$, but I plug in some number and found out they are not equal. What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: $x = \sqrt{u} \neq u$

Comment: Your forgot the $dx$ part in your substitution.

Comment: Because you get a factor of $\sqrt u$ that is unaccounted for in your substitution

Comment: If $u=x^2$ then $du=2x\,dx$ so $2x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx = ue^{-u}du/\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: Thank you guys. You're all right. I mistakenly thought $du=2dx$. That what happen after not having really calculated an integration after 10 year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating by parts would have been simpler than substitution
$$u=x\implies u'=dx$$

$$v'=2x e^{-x^2}dx\implies v=-e^{-x^2}$$ So $$\int 2x^2 e^{-x^2}dx=-x e^{-x^2}+\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \text{erf}(x)-e^{-x^2} x$$
$$\int_0^a2 x^2 e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \text{erf}(a)-a e^{-a^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $I(b)=\displaystyle\int_0^a e^{-bx^2}~dx.~$ Then our integral is $-2I'(1).~$ See also [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).